# I am attempting to search for the Cell header UPC and then add 4 columns to the right of the UPC with specific names

Tags: excel, vba

Here I am showing that the 4 columns are being added and then naming them. The goal is for it to search for the cell UPC and then add the 4 columns directly after that. I will use this macro on multiple sheets where UPC might have a different coordinate.

UPC will always be in row 1 and the following columns will always be in row 1, trailing the UPC cell. UPC will not always be in column A

````
'
' newcolumn Macro
' to amek comlumn
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
End Sub
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
' ok
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "My UPC"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MC ID"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "S/M"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DESC"
    Range("F1").Select
End Sub```
````

Comment: So UPC is in the same row as the four numbers and the names you title them with always go into row 1?  Is UPC always in column A?  Can it ever be in row 1?

Comment: Yes UPC will always be in row 1 and the following columns will always be in row 1, trailing the UPC cell. UPC will not always be in column A unfortunately.

Comment: So if it is always in row 1 you could just search: `Rows("1:1").Select: Selection.Find(What:="UPC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select`  followed by several of `Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight: Selection.Value = "X"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find()` to locate the header and then perform the insert based on that:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    Dim f As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:="UPC", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("My UPC", "MC ID", "S/M", "DESC")
    Else
        MsgBox "No UPC header found!"
    End If

End Sub
```